# How to transpose a matrix without MATLAB's transpose tool

Tags: matlab

I have an image, which I have listed as a matrix. I want to take the transpose of that image and then display that image on the screen.

I would like to know how to do this the "hard" way, ie without using MATLAB's transpose function.

Comment: Why use Matlab? use C or better, assembly. Matlab is designed to do it the easy way...

Comment: Are you trying to just avoid `transpose(x)`? What about `x'`? What about `permute(x,[2 1])`? Avoiding "the easy way" makes little sense... more context would be needed to really provide an answer.

Comment: This is part of an assignment for a matrix methods class... we are supposed to find the transpose of an image matrix and display it. I'm a MATLAB newb.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Presumably you just need to create a new matrix with row/column count reversed and then copy the data into it (reversing row & column index).

Comment: I know that a transpose takes each row of a matrix and makes it into a column of a new matrix. So row1 becomes column1 of a new matrix, row2 becomes colum2 of a new matrix, and so forth. I am just not sure how to actually write this into a piece of code.

Comment: If it's an assignment, you really should just figure this out on your own, but as a hint, you can do it using `size()` and `for` loops.

Answer (score 6):

```
function [B] = trans(A)
[r c] = size(A);
B = zeros(c,r);
for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
        B(j,i) = A(i,j)
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is for a class, I won't give you an exact answer, but I will nudge you in the right direction. I'm assuming that you are looking for a method that involves manually transposing the information, rather than using builtin functions.

Matlab stores values in a matrix in the form of a vector and a "size" - for instance, a 2x3 matrix would be stored with six values in a vector, and then [2,3] (internally) to tell it that it's 2x3 and not 6x1.

For the 2x3 matrix, this is the order of the values in the vector:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

To reference the value in (2,2), you can reference it as A(2,2), or as A(4). The value in (1,3) can be referenced as A(5).

As such, if you can construct a vector referencing the values in the transposed order, then you can assign the new values into the appropriate order and store them in a matrix of appropriate size. To make the point, consider the transpose of the above matrix:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

This would be represented as (1,3,5,2,4,6) with size (3,2). If you can construct the vector (1,3,5,2,4,6), then you can use that vector to assign the values appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's hint toward a solution: The transpose transforms the element `A(1,2)` from the normal array `A` into the element `B(2,1)` from the transposed array `B` (`B=A'`), and vice versa. Thus, you can iterate through all the rows and column, and apply the transformation element-by-element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) and [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) ?
In this case you can represent the transposition as a sequence of flips (I'll leave it to you to figure out the exact sequence).

Comment: I can't see how this should work. The single operations exchange columns between themselves and rows between themselves, they never exchange columns and rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use rot90 with flipud/fliplr for this.

Comment: You might need to make detailed explanation.